# Exception handling while searching JSON in webapp2

Tags: python, json, web-applications, keyerror

I'm trying to search a json array for an object. While some of the index don't have the object I'm searching for, I'm getting Keyerror there. How could I manage this exception in webapp2 ?

Comment: what is the traceback from your error?

Comment: photo_reference = data['results'][1]['photos'][0]['photo_reference']

KeyError: 'photos'


I'm searching for photos and get this error

Comment: I'm trying to search till the end of the json array. Is there any way to do that search. To define the limit of the search.

Comment: so "photos" is a key in the dict and your program is crashing when it does not exist?

Comment: I've got the exception handled using try and except. But now the problem is I'm not able to search till the end of the json. 
is there any way to do so.